# how to convert one multArray to one simpleArray javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have this situation in my application, one array with multiple arrays inside:

[image: multArray]

i need to convert this:

```
[
  {
    "tag": [
      {
        "key": "asdasd",
        "label": "asdasd"
      },
      {
        "key": "ddd",
        "label": "ddd"
      },
      {
        "key": "dwd",
        "label": "dwd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "tag": [
      {
        "key": "wdwd",
        "label": "wdwd"
      },
      {
        "key": "",
        "label": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "dwdw",
        "label": "dwdw"
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

to one single array like:

```
[
 0: {key: "...",label: "...."}
 1: {key: "...",label: "...."}
 2: {key: "...",label: "...."}
 .....
]
```

It's a react web application, so it need to be in javascript solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```
const result = data.flatMap(obj => obj.tag);
```

```js
const data = [{
    "tag": [{
        "key": "asdasd",
        "label": "asdasd"
      },
      {
        "key": "ddd",
        "label": "ddd"
      },
      {
        "key": "dwd",
        "label": "dwd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "tag": [{
        "key": "wdwd",
        "label": "wdwd"
      },
      {
        "key": "",
        "label": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "dwdw",
        "label": "dwdw"
      },
    ]
  }
];

const result = data.flatMap(obj => obj.tag);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: this is returning ```animalTags.flatMap is not a function``` and i'm using last version of node(16)

Comment: @FelipeMirandaDeLima well then it’s probably not an array

Comment: yes, you are right when i declarate i did this ```const [animalTags, setAnimalTags] = React.useState('');``` insted of this ```const [animalTags, setAnimalTags] = React.useState([]);```

Answer (score 0):

As TJ stated, you can use `Array.prototype.flatMap`, but be aware that you may need to copy the internal key-value pairs as well.

```js
const tags = [{
  "tag": [
    { "key": "asdasd" , "label": "asdasd" },
    { "key": "ddd"    , "label": "ddd"    },
    { "key": "dwd"    , "label": "dwd"    }
    ]
}, {
  "tag": [
    { "key": "wdwd"   , "label": "wdwd"   },
    { "key": ""       , "label": ""       },
    { "key": "dwdw"   , "label": "dwdw"   }
  ]
}];

const flattened = tags.flatMap(({ tag }) =>
  tag.map(({ key, label }) => ({ key, label })));
  
console.log(flattened);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Alternatively, you can reduce:

```js
const tags = [{
  "tag": [
    { "key": "asdasd" , "label": "asdasd" },
    { "key": "ddd"    , "label": "ddd"    },
    { "key": "dwd"    , "label": "dwd"    }
    ]
}, {
  "tag": [
    { "key": "wdwd"   , "label": "wdwd"   },
    { "key": ""       , "label": ""       },
    { "key": "dwdw"   , "label": "dwdw"   }
  ]
}];

const flattened = tags.reduce((accOuter, { tag }) =>
  tag.reduce((accInner, { key, label }) =>
    [...accInner, { key, label }], accOuter), []);
  
console.log(flattened);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a JSON String which you can convert to a JavaScript object with JSON.parse() like this...

```
var S='[
  {
    "tag": [
      {
        "key": "asdasd",
        "label": "asdasd"
      },
      {
        "key": "ddd",
        "label": "ddd"
      },
      {
        "key": "dwd",
        "label": "dwd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "tag": [
      {
        "key": "wdwd",
        "label": "wdwd"
      },
      {
        "key": "",
        "label": ""
      },
      {
        "key": "dwdw",
        "label": "dwdw"
      },
    ]
  }
]';


var TheObject=JSON.parse(S);
```